# Fetch multiple max values for mutually exclusive columns into a single row

Tags: mysql

I have a table say `call_memmo` which is having a column `chance_no` of `int` type. There are other two columns `is_group1` and `is_group2` both are `tinyint` type and are mutually exclusive. So I want to fetch `max(chance_no)` for `is_group1=1` and `is_group2=1` in a single query.

I tried this query

```
select if(is_group1 <> 0, max(chance_no), 0) as max_chance_group1,
       if(is_group2 <> 0, max(chance_no), 0) as max_chance_group2
from call_memmo
```

which gave result as

```
max_chance_group1   max_chance_group2
                0                   3
```

The output is wrong because `max_chance_group1` should come as `2`.

Then I tried this query

```
select (select max(chance_no) from call_memmo where is_group1 = 1) as max_chance_group1, 
       (select max(chance_no) from call_memmo where is_group2 = 1) as max_chance_group2

from call_memmo group by is_group1, is_group2
```

This is giving output correctly but multiple records are coming

```
max_chance_group1   max_chance_group2
                2                   3
                2                   3
```

I know that the query I used is not proper, so can anybody help me with a better way and get output in single row so that I can skip iteration?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this no need for group by

```
select (select max(chance_no) from call_memmo where is_group1 = 1) as max_chance_group1, 
       (select max(chance_no) from call_memmo where is_group2 = 1) as max_chance_group2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select (select max(chance_no) from call_memmo where is_group1 = 1) as max_chance_group1, 
       (select max(chance_no) from call_memmo where is_group2 = 1) as max_chance_group2
from call_memmo limit 1
```

or u can group your new column like

```
  select (select max(chance_no) from call_memmo where is_group1 = 1) as max_chance_group1, 
(select max(chance_no) from call_memmo where is_group2 = 1) as max_chance_group2 from call_memmo group by max_chance_group1, 
max_chance_group2
```